# What is the best way to convert all non display characters in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, character-encoding, string-decoding

I am loading data into a pandas `dataframe` from an Excel sheet and there are a lot of non display characters in many columns that I want to convert.

The most prevalent is an apostrophe being used in a contraction  ; e.g. `doesn't` which comes out as `doesnâ€™t`.

In the past I have used :

```
str.encode('ascii', errors='ignore').decode('utf-8')
```

but this required me to know which columns I needed to fix.

In this case I have 103 columns which could each contain this or other types of issues like this.

I am looking for a way to just replace any and all issues across the entire `dataframe`.

Is there a quick and easy way to do this over the entire `dataframe` without having to pass in each column to a function ?

Comment: Please try this : dataset=pd.read_csv(“Your_filename.csv”, encoding=”ISO-8859–1”)

Answer (score 0):

While reading the excel you should add `encoding='utf-8'`

```
df = pd.read_excel('App Stuff.xlsx', encoding='utf-8')
```

or use `encoding='unicode-escape'`

Comment: I tried your solution but i got this error `TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'`

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the best encodings which are suitable for your file with :

```
from encodings.aliases import aliases
alias_values = set(aliases.values())

for value in alias_values:
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(your_file, encoding=value) # or pd.read_excel
        print(value)
    except:
        continue
```

then open your file with the right encodings and see which one works best!